# How to model a supervisor tree in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

Let's say that I have a Zone dynamic supervisor (zone is a genserver), and each Zone has its own Player dynamic supervisor (player is a genserver).

So each Zone has many players, and I have many zones.

Is the way to do that just to store the PID of the Player supervisor in the Zone GenServer?

Is this the correct approach? And then when I start a Zone start a Player supervisor as well?

This is purely conceptual and I am new to doing this sort of thing. I would appreciate any learning resources on this as well!

Answer (score 4):

> just to store the PID of the `PlayerSupervisor` in the `ZoneGenServer`?

This would be not robust enough if the `PlayerSupervisor` crashes for some reason. One way would be to make `ZoneGenServer` trap exists of the respective `PlayerSupervisor` and also crash upon `PlayerSupervisor` crash, but that would mean you are implementing part of OTP already provided. I would go with the following (`ZoneSupervisor` is started with [`:rest_for_one` strategy](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.html#module-strategies), all others with `:one_for_one`):

```
           ————————————————————
           |  ZoneSupervisor  |
           ————————————————————
               ⇓          ⇓
————————————————————  ——————————————————
| PlayerSupervisor |  |  ZoneGenServer |
————————————————————  ——————————————————
         ⇓
————————————————————
|  PlayerGenServer |
————————————————————
```

Now when we are safe against crashes, the only thing would be to make `ZoneGenServer` aware of `PlayerSupervisor`. It might be done by asking `ZoneSupervisor` about its children and/or by [name registration](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) with `{:via, module, term}`. Using `PID` as a process handler is vulnerable to process restarts (due to crashes etc.) `PID` changes, the registered name does not.